# KeyError handling to set default to None using ItemLoader in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Going through scrapy tutorials and started using item loaders to gather data. The data that I am using involves reading from a pre-defined dictionary which I load through JSON and a product page that is followed by the spider.

The issue that I am having is that the dictionary will sometimes not have a key available (like 'salePrice') that causes a KeyError in the crawl and stops the execution altogether. I'm trying to see if there is a clean way to handle KeyErrors for this field in `items.py` where input_processors and output_processors are specified for each field.

Would appreciate any suggestions or examples!

```
import json
import re
import time

import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from tutorial.items import Product

class SephoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'sephora-shelf'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.sephora.com/shop/moisturizing-cream-oils-mists/?currentPage=1'
    ]
    next_page_number = 1
    base_url = 'https://www.sephora.com'


    def parse(self, response):
        json_xpath = '//script[@type="text/json" and @id="linkSPA"]/text()'
        product_container = json.loads(response.xpath(json_xpath).extract()[0])
        product_container = product_container['NthCategory']['props']['products']
        start_time = round(time.time())
        print("starting loop")
        for _product in product_container:
            product = Product()
            loader = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
            loader.add_value('list_price', _product['currentSku']['listPrice'])
            loader.add_value('sale_price', _product['currentSku']['salePrice'])
            loader.add_value('sku_id', _product['currentSku']['skuId'])

            loader.add_value('product_key', _product['productId'])
            loader.add_value('product_name', _product['displayName'])
            loader.add_value('brand_name', _product['brandName'])
            loader.add_value('product_id', _product['productId'])
            
            _product_url = self.base_url + _product['targetUrl']
            loader.add_value('product_url', _product_url)
            loader.add_value('status', None)
            print("finished loading product")
            
            # TODO: add a check to see if it was on the previous run's data
            #       to determine if it is product status: added / deleted.
            #       Only collect product data if the product is newly added.
            yield response.follow(_product_url, callback=self.parse_product,
                                  meta={'item':loader.load_item()})

        next_page_xpath = '//button[@type="button" and @aria-label="Next"]'
        next_page_button = response.xpath(next_page_xpath)
        print(f'next_page_button: {next_page_button}')
        
        if next_page_button:
            print("Inside next_page_button")
            SephoraSpider.next_page_number += 1
            next_page = re.sub('\?currentPage=[0-9]*',
                               '?currentPage=' + 
                               str(SephoraSpider.next_page_number),
                               response.request.url)
            print(f"Next Page: {next_page}")
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    
    def parse_product(self, response):
        loader = ItemLoader(item=response.meta['item'], 
                            response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('item_id', '//div[@data-at="sku_size"]')
        time.sleep(3)
        yield loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple workaround is to use the .get() method of dictionary and have it default to None when the key is missing. Still not convinced if this is a proper way of handling this kind of error when working with scrapy.

Before: `loader.add_value('sale_price', _product['currentSku']['salePrice'])`

After:  `loader.add_value('sale_price', _product.get('currentSku').get('salePrice', None))`